# how to remove elements with a common characters in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i would like to remove elements of the form ' + 0x^n' (except the last one if its in the form ' + 0x^0') from this list:

```
polynomial = ['-7x^5', ' + 0x^4', ' + 0x^3', ' + 4x^2', ' + 4x^1', ' + 2x^0']
```

i.e. the output should look like this:

```
['-7x^5', ' + 4x^2', ' + 4x^1', ' + 2x^0']
```

i tried looping through each element in elements followed by an if statement that would remove list elements with the third index being '0'(see code below)

```
res = []
for elements in range(0, len(polynomial) - 1):
    if polynomial[elements][3] == '0':
        polynomial.remove(polynomial[elements])
        res.append(polynomial)
    else:
        res.append(polynomial)
print(res[0])
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: not all ' + 0x^n' terms have been removed e.g. output: ['-7x^5', ' + 0x^3', ' + 4x^2', ' + 4x^1', ' + 2x^0']. the term ' + 0x^3' is still there.

Comment: So you want to remove the elements having or starting with `0x^` right ?

Comment: yes, except the last element if it were in the form ' + 0x^n'

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
polynomial = ['-7x^5', ' + 0x^4', ' + 0x^3', ' + 4x^2', ' + 4x^1', ' + 2x^0',' + 0x^0']
res=[]
for p in polynomial:
    if p==' + 0x^0' or p[:-1]!=' + 0x^':
        res.append(p)
print(res) #['-7x^5', ' + 4x^2', ' + 4x^1', ' + 2x^0', ' + 0x^0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regex :

```
polynomial = ['-7x^5', ' + 0x^4', ' + 0x^3', ' + 4x^2', ' + 4x^1', ' + 2x^0',' + 0x^0']

res = [i for i in polynomial if "0x^" not in i or "0x^0" in i]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
polynomial = ['-7x^5', ' + 0x^4', ' + 0x^3', ' + 4x^2', ' + 4x^1', ' + 2x^0', '0x^2'] 
res = []
s = "0x^" # delete string tag, you can input
for i in polynomial:
 if s not in i: 
    res.append(i)
print(res)
```